# giving string inputs and store them in a list without number limitation

Tags: python, list, loops, input

im kinda noob in programming. i want to save my daily study topics in a list, my code has topic number limitation(in range(3)) but i don't understand how to do it without number limitation.Any suggestion?

```
topics = []

for todays_topic in range(3):
    topics.append(input("inter here>> "))
    print(topics)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate??

Comment: You could use `while True` to loop indefinitely, or until you break from the conditional block.

Comment: tnx @Reti43 .. it works :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question but I'm guessing that you want to add your todays_topic to your list continuosly until you want to stop. It is better to use while loop instead of for loop. Use `while True` and keep adding elements. Take a variable and ask whether you want to enter more. If yes then continue, if no, then break the loop. Your code:

```
topics=[]
while True:
    todays_topic=input("Enter here>> ")
    topics.append(todays_topic)
    asc=input("Enter more?? Y/N: ")
    if asc=="N"
        break
```